# Tapping on notification unlocks my iPhone 8

Tags: iphone, notifications, lockscreen

When my iPhone is locked and I have notifications, certain ones allow me to touch the notification and it unlocks the iPhone without requiring me to authenticate by entering a passcode or Touch ID. Twitter specifically is the one that it happens with. Other notifications prompt me to authenticate via passcode or Touch ID.

I see this as a security threat. How can I disable this, so my iPhone always requires a passcode or Touch ID to unlock?

I am using an iPhone 8 running iOS 12.2.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) What is the model of iPhone that you are using?

Comment: iPhone 8. IOS 12.2

Comment: This shouldn't happen. Is it possible for you to share a motion capture of this happening to better understand what could be going wrong?

Comment: When you say "touch the notification" do you mean you're using a 3D (force) touch to expand the notification on your home screen?

Comment: I will try to get the motion capture.  What is happening is... my phone is locked and i see that there is a notification (from twitter in this example), all i do is touch it (no force), and it unlocks the phone and opens the twitter app to the message.  Does not happen with all notifications and it seems to happen most with Twitter notifications.

Comment: I've got the screen capture of the issue, how can I upload it here?  I'm not seeing an option to add a file.